# flutter ui emulator does not show image

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface, kotlin

I have a problem I started developing in flutter and I only used dart, it turned out that it asked me for multidex, I did as the example was shown and now I don't know how to solve a problem with the MainActivity.java and MainActivity.kt
problem

```
Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
e: C:\Users\diamar\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_s\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutter_s\MainActivity.kt: (9, 41): Unresolved reference: newBase
 Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
```

code
MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.flutter_s

import android.content.Context
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
        override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
               super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
               MultiDex.install(this)
       }}
```

Code MainActivity.java

```
 package io.flutter.plugins; import androidx.multidex.MultiDex; import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication;


 public class MainActivy extends MultiDexApplication {
     @Override
     protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
         super.attachBaseContext(NewBase);
          MultiDex.install(this);
     }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable multidex use this in /android/app/build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```